# PHP : PDO connection SQL and Missing Returned Data

Tags: php, sql, xaml, phpmyadmin

Please find below a script that scrapes an HTML table that should return data in my Database ( SQL|PhpMyAdmin ). I run the script in my browser using ( XAMPP)

The scraper works fine, it can display data in the browser or download as an excel file. I added a connection String to SQL using   [ **$conn = mysql_connect** ], However, I read this method its been deprecated and its better to use [**mysqli_connect** ] or ***PDO***.

**Questions :**

- If I use mysqli_connect, I dont encounter problems connecting to my database but the **returned data is missing some rows**. For example the table has 100 rows and I would just find 80 rows in the database. What could be causing that ? I dont think from the script otherwise I wouldn't see the complete results in the browser
- I tried the PDO ( see code below ) , the connection is successfull however no data is entered in my database. **Is there any syntax Error** ?

I don't mind using **mysql_connect** , **mysqli_connect** or **PDO** as long as I have all rows in my database without anything missing.

Please advise what connection String to use and why there are missing rows . The script is working well and returned data in browser is the same as the URL scraped.

**Code 1 : Using mysqli_connect Method** + Script overview

```
 $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "username", "password", "test");


 if (!$connection) {
printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
 exit();
  }

printf("Host information: %s\n", mysqli_get_host_info($connection));



$OutPut_Excel = $_GET['xls'];// 0 web page or 1 output excel
$show_Country = $_GET['show'];// 0 or 1
$urls = "
http://www.URL.com
";

 //output excel
if($OutPut_Excel == "1")
{
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-execl;charset=iso-8859-1");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.xls");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
 }

set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
ini_set('display_errors',true);


//output html
if($OutPut_Excel == "0")
{
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>scraper</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
</head>
<body>
<?php
 }

 if($OutPut_Excel == "0")
{
if($show_Country)
{
    $nameCountry = '<td>Country</td>';
}
 echo "<table border='1'><tr><td>Name</td><td>Surname</td>
<td>Email</td><td>Address</td><td>City</td><td>Profession</td>        <td>Phone</td>$Country</tr>";
 }
 else 
 {
echo "Name"."\t";
echo "Surname"."\t";
echo "Email"."\t";
echo "Address"."\t";
echo "City"."\t";
echo "Profession"."\t";
echo "Phone"."\t";
if($show_Country)
{
    echo "Country"."\t";
}

echo "\t\n";
    }

   include 'dom.php';
   $arrurl = explode(';',$urls);
   foreach ($arrurl as $u)
    {
$url = trim($u);
$html = file_get_html($url);
$string = $html->find("table[width=720]",0)->find("font[size=5]",0)->plaintext;
$arr = explode(' at ',$string);
$Satellite = trim($arr[0]);
$Degree = trim($arr[1]);


$k = 0;
foreach ($html->find("table[width=720]") as $d)
{
    $text = $d->outertext;
    $arr = explode('<td',$text);
    $out = "";
    foreach ($arr as $t)
    {
        $arr1 = explode('<font',$t);
        $count_font = count($arr1);
        $arr2 = explode('</font>',$t);
        $count_end_font = count($arr2);
        $need_count = $count_font-$count_end_font;
        $str = "";
        for($j=1;$j<=$need_count;$j++)
        {
            $str=$str."</font>";
        }
        if($out == "")
        {
            $out .= str_replace('</td>',$str,$t);
        }
        else 
        {
            $out .= "<td".str_replace('</td>',$str,$t);
        }
    }
```

**ECT... Some more code**

```
                            echo "$Name"."\t";
                            echo "$Surname"."\t";
                            echo "$Email"."\t";
                            echo "$Address"."\t";
                            echo "$City"."\t";
                            echo "$Profession"."\t";
                            echo "$Phone"."\t";
                            if($show_Country)
                            {
                                echo   "$Country"."\t";

    // SQL QUERY - WORKS FINE BUT SOME ROWS MISSING         
                        }
 $connection->query("INSERT INTO Directory (Name,Surname,Email,Address,City,Profession,Phone,Country) VALUES('$Name','$Surname','$Email','$Address','$City','$Profession','$Phone','$Country')");
```

**CODE 2 - PDO Connection - Returned Data is not entered in database**

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'username', 'password');

try{

                         $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO Directory(Name,Surname,Email,Address,City,Profession,Phone,Country) VALUES($Name, $Surname, $Email, $Address, $City, $Profession, $Phone, $Country)');
                         $stmt->execute(array('Name' => $Name, 'Surname' => $Surname, 'Email' => $Email, 'Address' => $Address, 'City' => $City, 'Profession' => $Profession, 'Phone' => $Phone, 'Country' => $Country));
                         $affected_rows = $stmt->rowCount();

                         } catch(PDOException $ex) {
                         echo "An Error occured!"; 
                         some_logging_function($ex->getMessage());
                         }
```

Comment: read the doc http://www.php.net/manual/fr/pdo.prepare.php

Answer (score 0):

On your mysql_query() function call you need to provide the database connection $conn.

It should be like this:

```
$sql = mysql_query("your sql query", $conn);
```

Re not all rows being inserted, it must be an error during the insert. Try modifying you code like this so MySQL errors are printed:

```
$connection->query("your sql query") or die(mysqli_error($connection));
```

Most likely it is an apostrophe ( ' ) somewhere in one of the values you are inserting. You may need to remove or escape them.

Comment: Also your example still uses **mysql_** functions, rather than **mysqli_** functions as you say in the title of **Code 1**.

Comment: Yes, sorry I copied the wrong script. Corrected. The mysqli_connect is working fine as I posted, but the data returned is missing in my database. I wonder why? is it a configuration problem? If it was from the script I would get all rows in my browsers.. Im not an expert, thats why im posting here. Thanks anyway for the remark

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO Directory(Name,Surname,Email,Address,City,Profession,Phone,Country) VALUES($Name, $Surname, $Email, $Address, $City, $Profession, $Phone, $Country)');
                         $stmt->execute(array('Name' => $Name, 'Surname' => $Surname, 'Email' => $Email, 'Address' => $Address, 'City' => $City, 'Profession' => $Profession, 'Phone' => $Phone, 'Country' => $Country));
```

to

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO Directory(Name,Surname,Email,Address,City,Profession,Phone,Country) VALUES(:Name, :Surname, :Email, :Address, :City, :Profession, :Phone, :Country)');
                         $stmt->execute(array(':Name' => $Name, ':Surname' => $Surname, ':Email' => $Email, ':Address' => $Address, ':City' => $City, ':Profession' => $Profession, ':Phone' => $Phone, ':Country' => $Country));
```

http://www.php.net/manual/fr/pdo.prepare.php

Comment: Thanks alot Jonathan. The PDO connection is working. However, I have in my database 82 rows( out of 100).. Why do you think there are missing rows ( I tried 3 methods). Is it from the script or Database settings?

Comment: Don't know, do you have `UNIQUE` fields?